# How can I increment a date in datetime64[ns] format by 6 calendar months?

Tags: pandas, datetime, increment, strptime

I never realised that incrementing a simple date in Python would be such an insurmountable challenge, but have given up after 2 hours of trying and searching on this forum. I have a dataframe with a column `effective_date`, which contains entries like `2019-01-02` and datatype `datetime64[ns]`.

I've tried:

```
data['effective_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['effective_date'].values)
data['six_mth_interval'] = data['effective_date'].apply(lambda x: x['effective_date'].values + relativedelta(months=6))
```

... but I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-315-b81c59eb6b0d> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 data['six_mth_interval'] = data['effective_date'].apply(lambda x: x['effective_date'] + relativedelta(months=6))

TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
```

Existing articles on S/O have not been helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
data['six_mth_interval'] = data.effective_date + pd.DateOffset(months=6)
```

For an example DataFrame the result is:

```
   effective_date six_mth_interval
0      2019-08-01       2020-02-01
1      2019-08-02       2020-02-02
2      2019-08-25       2020-02-25
3      2019-08-26       2020-02-26
4      2019-08-27       2020-02-27
5      2019-08-28       2020-02-28
6      2019-08-29       2020-02-29
7      2019-08-30       2020-02-29
8      2019-08-31       2020-02-29
9      2019-09-01       2020-03-01
10     2019-09-02       2020-03-02
```

Your code failed because when you apply a function to a *Series*
(a column of a DataFrame), then the argument is each **single**
element of this *Series*.

So you could write:

```
data['six_mth_interval'] = data['effective_date'].apply(
    lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(months=6))
```

but my code is faster.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - really appreciate it! Can't believe it took me so long to figure out, but one I'll remember going forward..